# print variable Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a dynamic variable names html print multiple inputs , what I do is this:

```
for( $t=0 ; $t < 2; $t++){
   $varservice[$t]='servicio'.$indexbook[$t];
}

for($j=0 ; $j < 2; $j++){
   $servicio[$j]=$request->get($varservice[$j]);
}
```

in the end, the service variable [ $ j ] , print null, it does not recognize the IndexBook variable that brings the name the html input and bring this information ... so that I can do? I print that variable comp .... I'm a driver

Comment: I'm sorry but I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. Could you please update your question to be a bit more precise?

Comment: plz update ur question .it hard to understand